# got multiple values for argument 'schema'

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe, sqlalchemy

```
    self.engine=create_engine("postgresql://postgres:12345@localhost/postgres")
            self.con = self.engine.connect()
            self.conn.autocommit = True
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

     
df.to_sql(symbol, schema='xxx', con=self.con, if_exists='append',
                      index=False)


    df.to_sql(symbol, con=self.con, if_exists='append',
                      index=False)
```

I am getting this error in both cases while adding the dataframe to the postgre sql database

```
meta = MetaData(self.connectable, schema=schema)
```

TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'schema'

Comment: Is `symbol` the name of the table? Looking at the latest docs I'm not sure quite how the second example could throw this error - what `pandas` version is this?

Comment: Actually, what is `MetaData`? I'm assuming that's SQLAlchemy, but you haven't shown how it's used. Please show the full traceback for the second method

Comment: sqlalchemy =2.0.0      pandas =1.3.5

Comment: pandas version= 1.5.3   fixed thanks @roganjosh

Comment: Take a  look at [Setting Alternate Search Paths on Connect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#setting-alternate-search-paths-on-connect) and [PostgreSQL search_path](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#remote-schema-table-introspection-and-postgresql-search-path).

Answer (score 6):

I just had this issue on Pandas 1.1.3 + SQLAlchemy 2.0.0. Updated to 1.5.3 and it was gone.

Answer (score 6):

The issue started just when my package got updated. It is working on these fixed versions.

pandas==1.1.5
SQLAlchemy==1.4.45

Comment: worked for me. fyi for others-- from a previous answer: the combo pandas=1.5.3, sqlalchemy=2.0.0 didn't work on my side.

Answer (score 1):

As is described in other comments and answers, this is an indication of a mismatch between pandas and SQLAlchemy version.

This usually happens when one software calls specific functions from the other which are requiring specific version, otherwise those functions will not exists and therefore an exception will throw.

There is another discussion which describes the same problem

> [df to table throw error TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'schema'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282511/df-to-table-throw-error-typeerror-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument)
>
> It seems that the version 2.0.0 (realeased on January 26, 2023) of
> SQLAlchemy is not compatible with earlier versions of pandas.

Please consider always to include your software versions into original question and not only in comments, this will help to understand faster the problem.